# Nested Trigger Too many SOQL queries: 101

Tags: trigger

I have two triggers A_Trigger and B_Trigger,

When A_Trigger is fired, B_Trigger could also be fired in the same transaction by a DML in A_Trigger.

I received an error message:

B_Trigger: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101

Can I assume it's always caused by an operation on Object B that fires B_Trigger directly?

Could it be an operation on A that caused this error?  e.g.  When an operation fires trigger_A which fires trigger B and in trigger B,  an SOQL query reaches the limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to make assumptions here. You can gather empirical data that will tell you exactly what is going on.

Start the Developer Console and change the Debug log levels so that DB category is at least INFO level. Make sure the Expiration date is somewhere in the future. Then hit the triggers and cause the limit exception. Open the resulting log and examine the SOQL queries that were made (`SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN`).

It should not be too difficult to sort them to see how many times each is occurring. You could even switch the Developer Console log viewer to the Analysis perspective and check the Execution Overview > Executed Units tab for the counts.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the log levels of APEX_PROFILING to FINEST (and turn off all the rest), and you'll get some nice details about what happened (Your Name > Developer Console > Debug > Change Log Levels... > Add/Change SFDC_Console settings). Here's an example from my dev org using a simple trigger:

```
15:19:12.203 (203473861)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING_BEGIN
15:19:12.203 (203473861)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|SOQL operations|
Trigger.AccountTrigger: line 6, column 1: [SELECT Name, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accounts]: executed 1 time in 11 ms
Trigger.AccountTrigger: line 5, column 1: [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE 'Test%']: executed 1 time in 8 ms
```

If you look near the end of each line, it tells you how many times the query was executed, and looking near the beginning, it tells you what line of code called the query, and which class or trigger it was called from.

Using this information, just look for the queries executed the most number of times and trace backwards through the code to figure out what's going on. Usually, it's simply a matter of one function being called in a loop.

Sometimes, it'll be because too many rows being updated, since records are "chunked" into groups of 200, if code updates 1000 rows of data, then the trigger for those rows will execute five times, thus producing as many as five times as many queries. In this case, you might need to explore caching or other alternatives to reduce the query count.

Comment: This is interesting.  I tested on my end and have a question now:  If the query's like this:   "for(Account a:[select id from Account]{  ...  }", If the returned row is 10 would the CUMULATIVE_PROFILING show 1 or 10?   I just ran some code in anonymous apex:  AnonymousBlock: line 2, column 1: [select id from account limit 100]: executed 203 times in 206 ms

Comment: @sfdcnoob That seems faulty. I just tried this on four records and came up with "executed 11 times in 18 ms". It seems like those loops are not counted correctly. I wonder if this is documented or if we've discovered a bug?